# How to print and read a list to(from) a file?

Tags: elisp, files

I'd like to save a (extremely minimal) database made of a lisp list and then read it back.

The list will look like something as follows:

```lisp
(:foo "bar" :baz "foobar" :foobaz "baz")
```

Are there some good ways to accomplish this?

I've tried something like this:

```lisp
(with-temp-file "filename" (insert (format "%s" sample-list)))
```

But this discards the quotes for the strings, and I wonder if I can read them back.

I also don't know if there's some good ways to read such a file to generate a list.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> (insert (format "%s" sample-list))
> ```

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `format` tells you:

```
%s means produce [...] any object with ‘princ’.
%S means produce any object as an s-expression (using ‘prin1’).
```

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Output Functions` to understand the difference between (and relevance to your question of) `princ` and `prin1`.

(But in short, change `%s` to `%S` or, better, just use `prin1` directly.)

For reading back you would typically `insert-file-contents` into a buffer and then `read`.

Comment: When serialising it's also worth keeping in mind the [global variables](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Variables.html) and [corresponding `prin1` arguments](https://gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Overrides.html) that can lead to data loss in case of list truncation for example.